# Planning for pregnancy and looking for new jobs

Tags: job-search, india, pregnancy

I am planing for a job change because it is inevitable (will be looking a job in India). At the same time, we are planning for a baby.
Maybe at the time I get a job offer I will be in a early stage of pregnancy.

I think it will be very awkward to disclose about my pregnancy to the potential employer, and also there will be great a risk to get a offer if I disclose it.

But I also have a guilty feeling that actually I am cheating them by hiding it, as I will be going for a 6 month maternity leave about 7 or 8 months after joining.

What will be the best to do in your opinion?

NB: I am 6 year experienced software engineer.

Comment: My mum was pregnant, with two kids with her in the van  and was still delivering goods - there are solutions. What about working from home start off small at 20% then increase as time goes...

Comment: In India getting a job which provides remote working is a terrible thing... Agian, if get a job like that, should I inform the employer about the pregnancy before joining?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere 6 months

Comment: Related, not a duplicate: [Starting a new job and disclosing pregnancy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118167/starting-a-new-job-and-disclosing-pregnancy)

Comment: This sort of stuff is why there’s employers out there that refuse to hire women in company-critical (e.g engineering) roles and pass off their discrimination as things like “that candidate was a bad fit for our culture”.

Comment: Employer have nothing to do that. Odds are that law even forbids them to ask it. You have all the reasons to assume that they will treat you unfairly if you admit it. If it does not help, lie some believable (like "we do not plan a child until we do not have our new home") and you have all the reasons to do that. Note, probably it won't help (bosses are not stupid) but it is the most what you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> also there will be great a risk to get a offer if I discloses it.

Yes, you are right. The enlightened ones / larger corps may give you an offer, but otherwise be prepared to be skipped from offers on disclosing the details.

> I have a guilty feeling that, actually I am cheating them, as I will be going for a 6 month maternity leave

Think: How would it have been any better if you went for pregnancy immediately after joining the job? 1 year after joining? 1 review cycle after joining?

The long leave is law mandated, not something of your own making. As such, don't feel guilty about it. What in the case you have a change of plans about the pregnancy? Any untoward incidents?

> about 7 or 8 months after joining

In which case, you can expect to work for 6-7 months for the company before you go on leave, which can be sufficient time duration for many IT projects to be complete.

> I am 6 year experienced software engineer. How can I handle this situation professionally?

Since you are feeling really guilty, avoid joining the companies/teams for whom you would be a critical resource. (Example, 3 developer membered startup with you as a lead engineer, critical timed project looking for senior engineer etc). As long as you join a place where you are one of many foot soldiers, a good manager should be able to manage things around.

Many companies today have programs for mothers who left their career midway for family commitment and are rejoining the industry after an extended break. So that is another route you can explore if your conditions permit - take a break at pregnancy for 1-2 years for child care and then join some place.

Comment: I don't know about India, but in many countries the "law mandated" part of the leave is 2 weeks before and 4-8 weeks after delivery. And I think that's very short, as a women who hasn't given birth before, so I am not picking on OP for choosing to take 6 months maternity leave. I just want to throw in that that is a leave longer than the legal "requirement".

Comment: @skymningen It is [6 months by law in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternity_Benefit_(Amendment)_Act,_2017#Key_Amendments)  _The Maternity Benefit Amendment Act has increased the duration of paid maternity leave available for women employees from the existing 12 weeks to 26 weeks_

Comment: That you get paid for 6 month does not mean that you legally have to take 6 months. But you usually have to legally (medically) take a few weeks in any case.

Comment: @skymningen Its a law. The act applies to the company, and labour laws in India can be very complex. So any well to do business will ensure in its own interest that the provisions are properly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would start planning a baby after at least 6 months in the new company. I cannot say for everyone, but for many of us, first couple of months at new place with new tasks, people, bosses and projects are a bit stressful. In this time I would strongly recommend **not** to plan a baby. You have to prepare yourself not only physically, bur also mentally to bring very happy healthy baby to the world. Also to this time you will have already stable source of money, what also will help the family.

If you definitely want to start earlier, well, there is no law, which restrict this. You don't need to lie, just not say anything about baby. It can hurt your career in this company, but you are experienced developer with many years experience. Without a problem you will find another job, if necessary.

Comment: I can't delay the pregnancy for some reasons as it will be a risk for me.. otherwise I will defiently go for it.

Comment: @NotDefined nature decides the conception date... unless it is in vitro...