# Should I bring up family expansion plans in interviews as a man?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, australia, gender

**Would it be beneficial or detrimental for a young man to reveal his family/relationship status during job interviews?** Would it be better to maintain an attitude of strict non-disclosure regarding your relationship situation? Or might it be advantageous to reveal that you are a young dad or planning to become one very soon?

While the situation is likely very different for a woman as discussed in [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118167/starting-a-new-job-and-disclosing-pregnancy) and [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/144983/planning-for-pregnancy-and-looking-for-new-jobs) question, is it different for men? Would a young father be seen as a more stable long-term employee than a young bachelor for instance?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115434/discussion-on-question-by-theironknuckle-should-i-bring-up-family-expansion-plan).

Comment: Seems unlikely..... only thing I can think of is he'd have lots of legit sounding excuses for missing work or being late.

Comment: Why would your personal life be a part of the interview, unless you trying to convey that you would need this job very much and being in a disadvantage be able to endure hardships :)

Comment: As an interviewer, I don't want to know, because under Australian law it's illegal for me to discriminate based on family status. If a candidate did disclose that info as an attempt to influence the outcome, I would be left thinking "do they understand that they're trying to get me to break the law?" This would not be a recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend not bringing it up unless you have *strong, specific* evidence or reason to believe a particular company/interviewer would view it as a positive, and maybe not even then.

Same advice applies to most things about yourself. Interviews already have a lot of ground to cover in a very short space of time so take their lead on what they want to know about and don't bring other things up unless they're important and directly relevant to the question at hand.

You might want to enquire as to the company's holiday, parental leave, and other policies before accepting a job offer. But that will come after any interviews are done, if they decide to offer you a job.

---

FWIW, if they do ask then I recommend being honest and straightforward. If they *are* going to discriminate against you for it, better you find that out now rather than once you've already started working there.

Comment: But if for the sake of argument the employer DID discover your relationship status and plans, how would it affect things?

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle Depends on the employer. We have no way of knowing so I wouldn't dwell on it too much.

Answer (score 3):

In an interview, I don't see why **you (as the interviewee)** would bring up anything about your personal life or personal plans. It's not the employers business.

If asked, then I would be as vague as possible, or maybe if you're applying for a job that involves working with families or children it could be an advantage.

In general I would avoid mentioning any plans to expand your family, as it could go against you, regardless of whether it's illegal or not in your area. - and being a father really doesn't say anything about how stable or responsible you are.

Post-interview. I've observed that it's a huge advantage for your employer to think you're in a relationship or have children. Those who do often get to leave work early, skip company social events without interrogation, and don't get forced or pressured into working unwanted overtime on the weekends.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that revealing your parental status and/or plans might be detrimental for your chances to get hired at a particular organisation.
For example when you applying at a start-up where they require insane working hours. Or at a smaller low-margin business where they balk at having to give you some parental leave soon.

However it also might work in your favor. A married person with (small) children to support is far less likely to suddenly go on a yearlong world-trip or deciding to have a radical change in career than a single person.

Therefore big organisations, for which it is important that employees commit to them for at least 5 years or longer, might see having a family with children as a plus.